# message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone

I'm having a table view of data. While scrolling my table 2 or 3 times so fast, its getting crashed. My gdb is telling like 
`"message sent to deallocated instance...."`

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Post the code for some one to be able to help you.

Comment: Just find out where you are releasing the object by mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, your reference counting has errors.

to find the object, enable NSZombies. enabling NSZombies will not free your objects -- but will generate runtime errors when you attempt to message an instance which would (under normal operation) have been deallocated. from there, you can learn more about the object (e.g. its type).

Instruments also has a NSZombie mode. it is very useful to point out an object/zombie's lifetime.

for more details, see:
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled

the link also details how you can configure your executable to run with zombies enabled. this is found in the section 'Use in Xcode'.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. but how to enable NSZombies(Project->Edit active Executable..)....?

Comment: @user 599561 i've updated the answer, and provided a link which will walk you through the process.